# How it arrange words to use qsort and string?

Tags: c++, qsort

Hellow I am a beginner in C++ programming.

I was studying the qsort and swap. Recently, I have a question concerning the computer programming.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void save();

int arrange(const void* a, const void* b) 
{
    int p = *(char*)a;
    int q = *(char*)b;

    if (p < q)
        return -1;
    if (p == q)
        return 0;
    return 1;

}
int main() {

       char work[] = "abc bbc lol faker";

    cout << " before//"<<work << endl;

    qsort(work, strlen(work), 1, arrange);

    cout <<"after//"<< work << endl;
}
```

But this program only put value(before// abc bbc lol fager after//aaabbcceefg...)

Q1. I want to arrange "Word". Use frist letter of word(apple->a) and Put the words in alphabetical order.

Example(intput:: abc, ckk, dcd --> program --> output:: abc, ckk, dcd)

I don't want this value "abcccddkk"...

What should I do?:(...

Comment: This is not C please use the right tag

Comment: Simple: first split sentence in words (hint: use a strstream and a vector<string>) then sort the vector of words

Comment: note that `std::sort` is strictly better than `qsort`

Comment: *I was studying the qsort and swap.* -- Hopefully you will learn that `qsort` is hopeless and leads to undefined behavior if you use it on non-POD types.  You should drop using it and use `std::sort`.  Change `work` to `std::string`, and you will see `qsort` no longer works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You have a single string, rather than an array of strings.

Try to declare `work` like this instead<sup>*</sup>:

```
const char* work[] = {"abc", "bbc", "lol", "faker"};
```

Next, your comparison function should use [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp) because we need lexicographical comparison of strings (the `<` operator on a `const char*` will compare memory addresses rather than contents of strings).

Use this:

```
int arrange(const void* a, const void* b) 
{
    const char* p = *(const char**)a;
    const char* q = *(const char**)b;
    return std::strcmp(p, q);
}
```

Finally, the call to `qsort` expects the number of elements, and then the size of each element, change it to this:

```
std::qsort(work, 4, sizeof(void*), &arrange);
```

#### [Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gTOES0IarHnOdS4U)

<sup>*otherwise you will need to tokenize the string by spaces to get them in an array</sup>

---

**Disclaimer**: This can all be done much easier with more modern C++ <sup>**</sup>

A C++11 solution would use [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) on a [vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (or [array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)) of [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string):

```
std::vector<std::string> words {"abc", "bbc", "lol", "faker"};
std::sort(words.begin(), words.end());
```

#### [Better Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ajEI2nhYnoB3P2ND)

<sup>**and it might get even better when ranges get standardized</sup>